# Mass replace names in vertex groups

Tags: python, scripting, rigging, armature, bones

I have a character that is setup with a rig and vertex groups. I want to switch to using Rigify. Rigify has the same bones as the current setup, but different names. To save time weight painting, I need to rename all the bone weight vertex groups to match the bone names used by Rigify instead of the current rig. So I need a tool or script that will take a bone name such as lowerarm_L and rename it to Forearm.L (or whatever rigify calls it.) I can make the bone name list myself.

I will need to do this on multiple characters, so making a script out of it would be very helpful. How can this be done?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The list of vertex groups can be found in the object properties, we just need to search for the names we want and rename them.

You could fill in `name_list` from the start or just add one or two names as you find them and re-run the script. This is set to rename vertex groups in the active object.

```
import bpy

name_list = [
    # old name - new name
    ['lowerarm_L','forearm.L'],
    ['lowerarm_R','forearm.R'],
    ['upperarm_L','upper_arm.L'],
    ['upperarm_R','upper_arm.R'],
]

v_groups = bpy.context.active_object.vertex_groups
for n in name_list:
    if n[0] in v_groups:
        v_groups[n[0]].name = n[1]
```

Note that matching names this way is case-sensitive, for an insensitive match use -

```
v_groups = bpy.context.active_object.vertex_groups
for n in name_list:
    for vn in v_groups:
        if vn.name.lower() == n[0].lower():
            vn.name = n[1]
```

Answer (score 5):

Have you looked into the [Name Panel Addon](https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?272086-Addon-Name-Panel-1-6-(Batch-Naming))?

It's really versatile batch naming tool for various data blocks, including *Vertex Groups* and batch name copying.

It even has some advanced features like *Auto Naming*, though I've never used those myself.

It's totally [free and open source](https://github.com/trentinfrederick/name-panel), although I'd consider [buying it over at the Blender Market](https://cgcookiemarkets.com/all-products/name-panel/) if you find it useful or if it helped you, simply to show encouragement and support to the developer.

I'm planing on doing it myself.

Comment: That looks really useful for a lot of things. I am still figuring out how to use it, but it does not seem to let me make a list of term to replace other terms with. I have to do it one at a time still? It looks like I'll still need a script if I want to rename all my groups from a pre made list with one click (although a script that calls this addon would probably be easier.)

Comment: The addon is quite powerful but also a bit hard to grasp at once. I only use a limited subset of the features myself, but as far as I know you can only find and replace one item at a time, so maybe a script that calls the addon is the solution. The author is quite open to suggestions, maybe he can come up with something although he mentioned being in the midst of a big rewrite, so he may not want to change much in the current addon iteration